# Minimize distance to a given point subject to a number of linear inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

I'm trying to find a point that has minimal distance to a known point and satisfies a number of linear inequality.

Example in two dimensions and one inequity:

$min\{$distance to $(50,70)$ | $x+40<=y\}$

The solution to this is $(40,80)$, which satisfies the constraint and has minimal distance to $(50,70)$.

I found this intuitively by drawing and I'm trying to figure out a way to solve this problem in $n$ dimensions and $n-1$ linear inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

In the e.g. above, you want to minimise $(x-50)^2+(y-70)^2$, s.t. $y-x \ge 40$.  By Cauchy Schwarz inequality, we get
$$\left((y-70)^2+(50-x)^2\right) \cdot (1+1) \geqslant (y-70+50-x)^2 =(y-x-20)^2 \geqslant 20^2 $$
with equality iff $(x, y) = (40, 80)$.

If there are multiple linear inequalities in $n$ dimensions, you may be able to extend the above, or in any case you can solve it as a generic quadratic optimisation problem, with positive definite objective and linear constraints.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part of your conclusion "equality iff $(x,y)=(40,80)$". Are you sure? I think we get equality as long as $y-x=40$, e.g. (60,100). But that doesn't minimise the distance.

Comment: There are two inequalities, the first attains inequality iff $y-70=50-x$, while the second iff $y-x=40$. Together they determine a unique point for equality.  In particular, $(60, 100)$ will not give equality - check yourself by evaluating.

Comment: Of course in the general case, there is no assurance of unique minimum, unless the inequalities determine a closed, convex feasible region.